# Axelor 6.0.8 and tomcat installation from source?

Tags: tomcat, axelor

I tried to install axelor erp from source on windows 10.
All is ok except the last operation. Deploy on tomcats.

Webapps was successfully created in tomcats but this error occured :

```
Message :   
ECHEC - L'application pour le chemin de contexte [/axelor-erp-6.0.8] n'a pas pu être démarrée
```

In english ;) :
FAILED - Application for context path [/axelor-erp-6.0.8] could not be started

I search on all related post but can't find a solution.
Can someone help me please ?

Here is the log from tomcats :

```
30-Mar-2021 09:57:58.904 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) [com.axelor.web.AppContextListener]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load application settings: C:\...\axelor-source\application.properties
        at com.axelor.app.AppSettings.<init>(AppSettings.java:60)
        at com.axelor.app.AppSettings.get(AppSettings.java:66)
        at com.axelor.app.internal.AppLogger.createLoggerConfig(AppLogger.java:34)
        at com.axelor.app.internal.AppLogger.install(AppLogger.java:53)
        at com.axelor.web.AppContextListener.contextInitialized(AppContextListener.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5171)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1015)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
30-Mar-2021 09:57:59.034 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte détruit (context destroyed) à l'instance de classe d'écoute [com.axelor.web.AppContextListener]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Guice is not initialized.
        at com.axelor.inject.Beans.get(Beans.java:45)
        at com.axelor.inject.Beans.get(Beans.java:58)
        at com.axelor.meta.loader.ViewWatcher.getInstance(ViewWatcher.java:101)
        at com.axelor.web.AppContextListener.contextDestroyed(AppContextListener.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4751)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5415)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1015)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
30-Mar-2021 09:58:36.479 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) [com.axelor.web.AppContextListener]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load application settings: C:\...\axelor-source\application.properties
        at com.axelor.app.AppSettings.<init>(AppSettings.java:60)
        at com.axelor.app.AppSettings.get(AppSettings.java:66)
        at com.axelor.app.internal.AppLogger.createLoggerConfig(AppLogger.java:34)
        at com.axelor.app.internal.AppLogger.install(AppLogger.java:53)
        at com.axelor.web.AppContextListener.contextInitialized(AppContextListener.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5171)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1386)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:697)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:218)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:669)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1629)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
30-Mar-2021 09:58:36.601 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte détruit (context destroyed) à l'instance de classe d'écoute [com.axelor.web.AppContextListener]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Guice is not initialized.
        at com.axelor.inject.Beans.get(Beans.java:45)
        at com.axelor.inject.Beans.get(Beans.java:58)
        at com.axelor.meta.loader.ViewWatcher.getInstance(ViewWatcher.java:101)
        at com.axelor.web.AppContextListener.contextDestroyed(AppContextListener.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4751)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5415)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1386)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:697)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:218)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:669)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1629)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

After few hours, I found my solution.

If I ignore this step of Axelor developer guide :

[Deploy your app step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiJiy.png)

I use directly the application.properties in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\axelor-erp-6.0.8\WEB-INF\classes"

It works for me now.